# Getting 403 error when I import the spotify API

Tags: javascript, spotify

I got an error 403 when I was trying to import with the spotify API the top tracks song:

[image: the error console message]

The code seems good, I don't really know where is the problem.

```
const TRACKS = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/tracks";

function getSongs(){
    callApi("GET", TRACKS, null, handleSongResponse)
}
```

i'm trying to import the top tracks spotify , but i get this 403 error.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Forbidden usually means that either you didn't have the necessary scope when you requisitioned your access tokens, or your access token expired.

Check to make sure that you have the correct scope, that your access tokens are still valid, and if your tokens were revoked.

Comment: Does the Spotify API require some kind of authentication token?

Comment: related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Comment: I don't know how to make sure that i have the correct scope, but my access tokens are still valid.

Comment: Do the reponse headers provide any further information why you're not authorized?

Comment: Always post errors as text with some formatting and not as an image please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a token that can access **user** data, so one of these type of token: `Authorization code`, `Authorization code with PKCE` or `Implicit grant`.

Using `client authorization` will result in a 403.

[image: Tokens authorization]

Authorization code example: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow

Authorization code with PKCE exaple: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-pkce-flow

Implicit grant example: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/implicit-flow

Comment: @CAROTORO glad I helped. Don't forget to accept the answer to help anyone needing this in the future.